# What investment is best?

Tags: investing, savings, bonds

I recently started a savings account that gets me .015% and a CD of .025%.  I want to increase my investments as fast as I can.  I don't want to go into stocks; I would prefer bonds and notes. What will give me a better return on my investments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bonds are the better choice, and also I would recommend ETFs. Bonds from wealthy countries with a long duration life time and at least more % than the annual inflation could be good for to keep your money together. However for to increase your accounts balance, you have to take a little more risk. An ETF like one that covers the MCSI World Index could be an idea for you. It´s relatively safe and still profitable. The MCSI includes almost 85% of the free float-adjusted market capitalization, means it contains investments from the whole world, makes it also well allocated and security oriented. You can also have a look at the Russel3000 ETF from ishares, very nice risk/profit ratio. There are plenty more, you may could ask your local Bank for more. Regards